# Neo4j Server certificate is not trusted

Tags: encryption, neo4j, certificate, lets-encrypt, neo4j-driver

I have just set up my Neo4j server on a VM on Google Cloud, I'm using Enterprise version 4.1.1, and I've have finished following the great post ([here](https://medium.com/neo4j/getting-certificates-for-neo4j-with-letsencrypt-a8d05c415bbd)) by David Allen about how to get a certificate with LetsEncrypt.

This has all worked perfectly and I now have a fully secure Neo4j server that I can access through the browser (`MYDOMAIN.COM:7473/browser`) using my hostname. However, I am now having issues getting my application to connect to the server using the javascript driver.

I keep getting the following error:

> Failed to connect to server. Please ensure that your database is
> listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible
> encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the
> default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. Caused by: Server
> certificate is not trusted. If you trust the database you are
> connecting to, use TRUST_CUSTOM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES and add the
> signing certificate, or the server certificate, to the list of
> certificates trusted by this driver using neo4j.driver(.., {
> trustedCertificates:['path/to/certificate.crt']}). This is a security
> measure to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks. If you are just
> trying Neo4j out and are not concerned about encryption, simply
> disable it using encrypted="ENCRYPTION_OFF" in the driver options.
> Socket responded with: ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID

I have read through the driver documentation ([here](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/function/index.html)) and I have added both the `trust: "TRUST_CUSTOM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES"` and `trustedCertificates:[]` settings. I downloaded all of the certificates from my server (cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem and privacy.pem) and linked to them in the trustedCertificates setting.

Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. For reference, this is how my driver is currently configured:

```
// This module can be used to serve the GraphQL endpoint
// as a lambda function

const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-lambda')
const { makeAugmentedSchema } = require('neo4j-graphql-js')
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

// This module is copied during the build step
// Be sure to run `npm run build`
const { typeDefs } = require('./graphql-schema')

const driver = neo4j.driver(
  process.env.NEO4J_URI,
  neo4j.auth.basic(
    process.env.NEO4J_USER,
    process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD 
  ),
  {
    encrypted: process.env.NEO4J_ENCRYPTED ? 'ENCRYPTION_ON' : 'ENCRYPTION_OFF',
    trust: "TRUST_CUSTOM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES",
    trustedCertificates: ['../../certificates/cert.pem', '../../certificates/chain.pem', '../../certificates/fullchain.pem', '../../certificates/privkey.pem'],
    logging: {
      level: 'debug',
      logger: (level, message) => console.log(level + ' ' + message)
    },
  }
)

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: makeAugmentedSchema({ typeDefs }),
  context: { driver, neo4jDatabase: process.env.NEO4J_DATABASE },
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
})

exports.handler = server.createHandler()
```

I'm using the latest build of the driver, v2.14.4 and have enabled full logging but I'm not getting any more information than the above. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem - I had a look at the documentation ([here](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/client-applications/?_ga=2.179556707.677712208.1595597531-1311114630.1592812253#driver-connection-uris))and found that I needed to update my `NEO4J_URI` from `bolt://SO.ME.IP.ADDRESS:7687` to `neo4j://MYDOMAIN.COM:7687`. Now I've done this all is working as expected.